# Prevent highlighting of map tiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps

I notice that sometimes when clicking around the map, the map tiles get highlighted as shown. Is there anyway to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: i really don't understand the problem. is that what you see when you click arround the map??

Comment: I believe it is when I do a click outside the map and drag it across the map while holding down the mouse button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means selection which can be prevented depending on browser:

CSS:

```
.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".unselectable").bind("selectstart", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```